# Why isn't IO an instantiation of State?

Tags: haskell, io, state, monads, monad-transformers

Why isn't `IO` an instantiation of the (strict) `State` monad when we have `RealWorld`, as provided in `Control.Monad.ST`? I thought `RealWorld` were meant to be a magical type representing the reality itself.

I mean, recall the "run" function of the `State` monad:

```
runState :: (s -> (a, s)) -> s -> a
```

Instantiating this to `RealWorld`, we get this:

```
runIO :: (RealWorld -> (a, RealWorld)) -> RealWorld -> a
```

Since we cannot construct a value of `RealWorld` *anyway*, this shouldn't act as a backdoor like `unsafePerformIO`.

Is the reason because this interpretation would enable the monad transformer `IOT`, defined as `StateT RealWorld`?

Comment: People aren't supposed to be explicitly dealing with `RealWorld` in any way whatsoever. It's an implementation detail.

Comment: Recall also that we provide `state :: ((s -> (a, s)) -> State s a`. What, then, should `state (\realWorld -> (runState getLine realWorld, realWorld))` do? On its surface, it looks like it might let you rerun `getLine` again on that same `realWorld` with bind, which seems hard for the implementation to actually achieve.

Comment: At the very least this would require some linear typing to prevent `RealWorld` values being duplicated. Doing so would allow one, for instance, to return to an old world state after side effects are performed, which is impossible to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Exposing the `RealWorld` in `IO` still gives you `getUnsafePerformIO :: IO (IO a -> a)` which is just as bad as `unsafePerformIO`.
2. `IO` uses unlifted types (`RealWorld#`, `(#,#)`) to avoid unnecessary allocations, so it doesn't exactly match `State` anyway.
3. It does match `ST`, but a direct definition of `IO` minimizes the noise whenever you look at Core or need to do some low level hacks (which are much more common than uses of `ST` that also involve `IO`).
4. > I thought `RealWorld` were meant to be a magical type representing the reality itself.

   `RealWorld` is a cute name but mostly a source of confusion. It really doesn't represent anything. It's best to forget `RealWorld` means anything and think of this definition of `IO` only in terms of operational semantics.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of `IO` is to carefully define a model in the pure universe of Haskell values, constructed so that everything you can do with the model matches up to actual behaviour of the real universe. Then we can hook up particular APIs in the model with actual real-world observations and effects.

If `IO` were simply `type IO a = State RealWorld` it wouldn't do that job. Even though we can't construct a `RealWorld`, we can still do things with this interface that simply don't make any sense in terms of the behaviour of the real universe.

```
main = do
  backup <- get
  fireMissiles
  tears <- checkForRegrets
  if tears
    then put backup
    else pure ()
```

So a key part of Haskell's pure model for IO is that the `IO` type is *abstract*. It has no directly observable properties *except* for the fact that it implements the `Monad` class and the provided primitive operations.

You can certainly mentally model `IO` as "it's like a state monad, where the state being threaded through represents the entire universe". On that understanding, combining `IO` actions is arranging "the universe" to be threaded through them all in the right order.

Many Haskellers (including myself) prefer the mental model that an `IO a` is a pure *description* of an impure action; something like "a program that claims running it will produce an `a`". On that understanding, combining `IO` actions is hooking up later programs to be run as continuations with the results produced by earlier ones.

But neither of those models is exactly how `IO` "really works" under the hood. `IO` is *like* both of those those things, but mostly that's because the API of an unknown abstract monad is like both of those things, and "it's a monad" is really the only declarative information that `IO`'s public API has. You can use whichever way of thinking about it helps you the most (I have a pet theory that people coming from "traditional" imperative programming find the state monad analogy easier, and people who are comfortable with continuation passing styles find the "description of an action" more appealing). But regardless of how you think of it, the type checker and the module system will enforce the actual properties that matter (unless you go out of your way to import and use unsafe things).

There is something that looks like world-passing going on in the **implementation** of `IO`; this is where the `RealWorld` type you've noticed is used. It's essentially an implementation technique to help ensure the compiler doesn't accidentally decide to reorder IO operations; it works by making the desired order of operations appear (to the compiler) to have a data dependency requiring that order. But if you have access to that level you are *not* restricted to writing sensible code that actually corresponds to the way IO operations behave in the real world, so this world-passing is *not* part of the public API of `IO`. The fact that it's there as an implementation detail does not mean that you have to or even should think of `IO` as a state monad, any more than you need to think of a `Map` or a `Set` as a a tree.

Some other languages (Clean and Mercury are the ones I am aware of) **do** use world-passing more explicitly, and actually provide direct access to the world tokens. To do this and keep the property that anything you can do in the pure model of IO actually corresponds to things that can be done in our single real universe requires a different kind of restriction. Clean and Mercury use uniqueness types; essentially the `World` you are given has a type-level marker that makes sure it must be used *exactly* once (note that in Clean and Mercury the world token *itself* is still completely abstract; the *existence* of the world token is part of the API, but you still can't look inside them or do anything with them except pass them to the next IO operation). This prevents the kind of "backup universe" nonsense I wrote earlier. If Haskell actually wanted to model IO with world passing it could but it would also need to use something like uniqueness types, so it still could not use the ordinary `State` monad.